# Replacing the token value in the HTML text content

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a token value

`echo variable_get('some_count', '');exit;`

This prints 23. But if I try to use the same in the HTML code. I am getting error.

```
$sone_cnt = '
        <div>

        <p class="sub-heading">How to help , '

        echo variable_get('provider_count', '');

        'number of people</p>

    </div>';
```

I am new to PHP. Let me know, if anything else is needed to be done here to get this value in the html content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to break out of the string to call the function, and concatenate with the dot

```
$sone_cnt = '
    <div>

    <p class="sub-heading">How to help , '.

    variable_get('provider_count', '').

    'number of people</p>

    </div>';
```

Comment: Thak you very much . I had missed the dot. It works perfectly.